# error when I trying to make my C++ project using CPR and TorchScript Library

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, request, libcurl

I am trying to use CPR to get Post Request from an API but when I make my project using Cmake, it always error. Let's have a look at my CMakeList.txt, code and error.

Any ideas are very good to me. Thank in advance my bros.

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Preprocessing)

add_subdirectory(cpr)

add_executable(Preprocessing main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/bao/CLionProjects/Preprocessing/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

target_link_libraries(Preprocessing ${CPR_LIBRARIES} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set_property(TARGET Preprocessing PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS} ${CPR_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

my code:

```
void query_split_text_service (std::string s){
    json j;
    j["sentence"] = s;

    std::cout<< j << std::endl;

    auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"http://127.0.0.1:8880/nlp/tone"},
                        cpr::Body{j.dump()}
    );
    std::cout << r.text << std::endl;
}
```

and error:

```
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable Preprocessing
CMakeFiles/Preprocessing.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void cpr::priv::set_option<std::string>(cpr::Session&, std::string&&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3cpr4priv10set_optionISsEEvRNS_7SessionEOT_[_ZN3cpr4priv10set_optionISsEEvRNS_7SessionEOT_]+0x2a): undefined reference to `cpr::Session::SetOption(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Preprocessing.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'Preprocessing' failed
make[2]: *** [Preprocessing] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:346: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Preprocessing.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Preprocessing.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

but If comment some lines, the miracle that I can make my project and run it.

```
void query_split_text_service (std::string s){
    json j;
    j["sentence"] = s;

    std::cout<< j << std::endl;

//    auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"http://127.0.0.1:8880/nlp/tone"},
//                        cpr::Body{j.dump()}
//    );
//    std::cout << r.text << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `${CPR_LIBRARIES}` how does that get populated since you are not using find_package()?

Comment: @dreschejm add cpr subdirectory to your CMakeLists.txt will produce two CMake variables, CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS and CPR_LIBRARIES.

Comment: It must be something specific to the `CPR` library. This is not a standard `CMake` feature or a feature I have seen with any other library I have used with `CMake`

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr) the repository you are using?

Comment: @drescherjim Yeppp, I think it using subdirectory

Comment: @squareskittles yepp, exactly it

Comment: I looks like somehow your CPR libraries are not **linked** correctly; you need to *debug* your CMake to see what went wrong. What are the *contents* of `${CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${CPR_LIBRARIES}`? You can use `message(${CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS})` to print out their contents as CMake runs...

Comment: @squareskittles hi, but when i run it alone, without using any library just CPR, it running correctly. Can u help me to debug it?

Comment: Just add `message(${CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS})` and `message(${CPR_LIBRARIES})` to the end of your CMake file and re-run CMake. Please tell me what prints out.

Comment: @squareskittles message(${CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS}) : "/home/bao/CLionProjects/Preprocessing/cpr/include" and message(${CPR_LIBRARIES}) : "cpr". Thank u for the kindness

Comment: Those results appear to be correct, so I'm not sure what might be wrong.

Comment: @squareskittles Do u have any ideas to fix it?

Comment: The line `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` should be issued **before** `add_executable` call, otherwise it has no effect. Variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` could be appended anywhere, but it is better to set it near the beginning (but **after** `project()` call).